# How to strip out part of a bread crumb path in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In my database, I have the following column BreadCrumb which has entries per row as:

```
Root->Music by Artist->Kylie
Root->Music by Artist->Beyonce->2009
Root->Music by Artist->Beyonce->2008
Root->TrashCan 
Root2->Demo Content->Building 1
```

How do I execute a query to give me a column which just contains "Music by Artist" and "Demo Content" (no duplicates)?

Comment: (Not the downvoter) What have you tried? Are you storing these as strings? If so, you should probably be using arrays or at least strings delimited by single chars that're easily split without a regexp.

Comment: Currently stored as strings, the UI i am working with put those values in. Tried to do RegEx but I need to spend a few hours learning how to use it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a lot of nice string functions (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT DISTINCT split_part(crumbs,'->',2)
FROM table1
WHERE split_part(crumbs,'->',3)<>'';
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/600c7/5

Comment: Thank you so much. I was about to read up on regex (I'll save that for another day).